# apparmor.service fails with apt install (status=1/FAILURE), Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, apparmor

I've searched far and wide on the Internet, and this problem looks decidedly different than the "apparmor fails status=123" issues I've seen.

Basically, whenever I try to run anything with apt (apt install, apt --fix-broken install, apt remove) I get the following (it fetches the database, reads the database, then):

```
Removing cqrlog (2.0.5-3ubuntu1) ...

Changes removed from /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
Restarting apparmor...

Job for apparmor.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apparmor.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apparmor, action "restart" failed.
* apparmor.service - AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-02-19 11:37:06 CST; 14ms ago
     Docs: man:apparmor(7)
           http://wiki.apparmor.net/
  Process: 4571 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apparmor start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4571 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 19 11:37:06 lenovo-laptop systemd[1]: Starting AppArmor initialization...
Feb 19 11:37:06 lenovo-laptop apparmor[4571]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Feb 19 11:37:06 lenovo-laptop apparmor[4571]:  * Mounting securityfs on ...
Feb 19 11:37:06 lenovo-laptop apparmor[4571]: mount: : mount point does not exist.
Feb 19 11:37:06 lenovo-laptop apparmor[4571]:    ...fail!
Feb 19 11:37:06 lenovo-laptop systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 19 11:37:06 lenovo-laptop systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 19 11:37:06 lenovo-laptop systemd[1]: Failed to start AppArmor initialization.
dpkg: error processing package cqrlog (--remove):
 installed cqrlog package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cqrlog
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Suggestions of "install snap" of course won't work, since I can't install anything.  I'm not new to Ubuntu (user since around 10 or 11, FreeBSD user since 1999. . .), but I'm new to apparmor, as I've never had any issues with it.

How do I proceed?  Thanks!

Comment: Any way to totally remove apparmor and reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in the same ubuntu version however my problem was with the service `spice-vdagentd.service`.

I fixed it by doing something very simple: Removing the service from my computer:

`sudo apt-get remove spice-vdagentd.service`

so in your case you could try:

`sudo apt-get remove apparmor.service`

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for the feedback I will update my answer right now.